# Access was attempted on a file that contains unicode characters in its path, but somehow the current locale does not support utf-8

Tags: python, django, utf-8, mezzanine

I designed a website using **django mezzanine** platform and it goes completely alright. I just have a problem with ***utf-8 numbers*** which I used in pages (actually persian numbers).
you see, in django templates it shows numbers as english digits, and when I wanted to show numbers in persian(utf-8) i had to use a custom template tag, which transform all numericals into persian. (I provided the code).
but in mezzanine templates it also had to use another custom template tag which implements html tags in WYSIWYG editor.
my problem is when I want to combine these 2 template tags it breaks. especially when the page has image in it. consider the "richtext_filters" use the width and height provided by string, and the numbers before getting to them has changed to utf-8 digits, and then the error I entered as the title appears:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u06f1' in position 83: ordinal not in range(128)
```

or the other error:

```
Access was attempted on a file that contains unicode characters in its path, but somehow the current locale does not support utf-8. You may need to set 'LC_ALL' to a correct value, eg: 'en_US.UTF-8'.
```

I also considered changing "locale" on my shared host provider, but didn't have any clue either.
appreciate any help.

---

any code needed is here:
my custom template tag:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import template
from datetime import datetime

@register.filter(name='persianize_digits')
def persian_int(string):
    persianize = dict(zip("0123456789",'۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹'))
    return ''.join(persianize[digit] if digit in persianize else digit for digit in str(string))
```

and also the template:

```
{{ page.richtextpage.content|persianize_digits|richtext_filters }}
```

if you want to know the "richtext_filters", here it's the code: ([mezzanine.utils.html](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/utils/html.py))

```
        width = img.get("width")
        height = img.get("height")
        if src_in_media and str(width).isdigit() and str(height).isdigit():
            img["src"] = settings.MEDIA_URL + thumbnail(src, width, height)
```

Comment: FYI, see [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for a faster translation method.  for example: `persianize = str.maketrans('0123456789','۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹')` then `return string.translate(persianize)`.

Comment: You have two different problems. One: you use UTF-8 in filenames (maybe you should *slugify* filenames. and the second problem: you try to write to a ASCII file characters that are outside ASCII.

Comment: thanks a lot @MarkTolonen, i didn't knew it. very appreciated.

Comment: thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi . I didn't pay enough attention. one of my pages has 2 pics with number in its filename. I changed the filename and the first problem has gone. but for the main problem I don't get what to do. to combine 2 different template tags besides each other.

Comment: for the ascii problem, could you tell us more which line complain? To me, it smells that you are `print`ing something on console, and console do not support UTF-8. In that case, look for a locale (command `locale -a`), then select it `export LANG=<such_locale>` (choose one with UTF-8). But it could be also on accessing other files... we need more info.

Comment: In any case, I never look linked information on questions. If you think there are important stuff, you should include in the question. This is a reference site: we hope people in future (with similar problem) can look this question and the answer. Links may go away. So the question should be self contained.

Comment: thanks @GiacomoCatenazzi, I didn't pay attention. sure I will do.